# How to scale Movie graphic/animated GIF?

Tags: android

Is it possible to scale a Movie graphic that is an animated GIF?

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.myGif);
myMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
myMovie.draw( canvas, ...);
```

This is how I am adding my GIF to a canvas. I have read that I can use:

```
canvas.scale();
```

But this scales the whole canvas, I just want to scale the movie graphic?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 canvas.save()
 canvas.scale(....)
 // draw on canvas
canvas.restore()
```